# Image Picker is not working when try to select multiple images

Tags: jquery, image, debugging, jquery-plugins, picker

I am using this Image Picker jQuery plugin (http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/) to show pictures and make multiple selection

All things is work If I use normal selection like this.

```
<select class="image-picker">
```

but when I try to use multiple selection by include attribute multiple

```
<select class="image-picker" multiple="multiple">
```

All images is freeze and cannot select and I can't select even one image.

This is my source code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <style>


  .image_picker_image {
            max-width: 140px;
            max-height: 100px;
            background-color: #FF0000;
        }
    </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="image-picker/image-picker.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="image-picker/image-picker.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("select").imagepicker();
            });
        </script>


    </head>
    <body>

        <!--code for imagepicker-->
        <select class="image-picker" multiple="multiple">
            <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/220/200" value="1">Cute Kitten 1</option>
            <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/180/200" value="2">Cute Kitten 2</option>
            <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/130/200" value="3">Cute Kitten 3</option>
            <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/270/200" value="4">Cute Kitten 4</option>
        </select>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Working fine http://jsfiddle.net/mgvrc/246/

Comment: found it.I've forgotten that jquery should do not have type="text/javascript" in side script tag.

But however I'm really thank you for your help. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use timeout to push images. 
I think that sorts out memory issue by pushing the images one by one at an interval:

```
this.imagePicker.getPictures({
        maximumImagesCount: 10,
        width:512,
        height:512,
        outputType: 1 ,
        quality:45
     }).then((results) => {
       for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
         if(results[i] ){
           let thisimg = {
               "src":'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + results[i] 
           };
           setTimeout(()=>{
            this.imageLists.push( thisimg );
           },1000) 
           //this.imageLists.reverse();
         } 
       }  
    }, (err) => { 
        this.events.publish("toast",err);
});
```